# Laravel Mysql Update parse error

Tags: php, lumen

```
    $user = DB::update('update users set name = '100' where id = ?', $id);
    print_r($id);
```

the `$id` is `1` and when I run the above I get the following:

> FatalErrorException in UpdateUsers.php line 83: parse error

Line 83 is `$user = DB::update('update users set name = '100' where id = ?', $id);`

Answer (score 2):

Syntax error, try this.

```
DB::table('users')
        -> where('id', $id)
        -> update(['name' => 100]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got to be mindful of your starting and ending single quotation marks, and your starting and ending double quotation marks.
For example, **you cannot do this:**

```
$user = 'I have what you call a 'variable' located here';
```

You can, however nest double quotation marks within single quotation marks like this:

```
$user = 'I have what you call a "variable" located here';
```

or you can escape nested single quotation marks like this:

```
$user = 'I have what you call a \'variable\' located here';
```

So for your line which is causing a Parse error (this is not how DB), it should be this:

**Avoid using this, as it is not the official Laravel way, see Laravel docs:**

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database

```
$user = DB::update('update users set name = \'100\' where id = ?', $id);
```

or

```
$user = DB::update('update users set name = "100" where id = ?', $id);
```